# Работа с ответом REST API

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Доброго времени суток. Работаю с vue, получаю ответы от сервера следующего вида:

```
let data = [
0: {id: 12,}
1: {id: 77,}
2: {id: 565,}
];
```

Т.е. массив объектов. И ключи массива бесполезны. Чтобы получить объект у которого внутри есть id 565 - нужно перебрать весь массив, проверять и т.п. Или же при получении данных от сервера сразу перевести всё в массив с нужными ключами

```
let data = [
    ...
    12: {id: 12,}
    ...
    77: {id: 77,}
    ...
    656: {id: 565,}
    ];
```

Но тогда пустые ключи будут всё равно в массиве, создавая огромный почти пустой массив.

Какие вообще есть подходы? Как быть?

Comment: Почему бы не формировать нужный массив прямо на сервере?

Comment: @ZhukovRoman Потому что рушится идея REST API. В итоге, получится, что для одного прилажения подходят в таком виде, а для другого - нет. Лучше всё в одном виде получать. А уже на стороне прилажения крутить - я так думаю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте объект:

```
let data = {
    12: {id: 12,}
    77: {id: 77,}
    656: {id: 565,}
};
```

И не будет пустых ключей.